# Is the Receive Marketing Emails field on a Customer available through the Bigcommerce API?

Tags: bigcommerce

The Bigcommerce admin area shows a Receive Marketing Emails field for a Customer. This field does not appear in the API response data or the documentation for the Customer entity in the documentation.

Is there some way to access this value through the API?

Answer (score 0):

I learned from Bigcommerce support that the Receive Marketing Emails field cannot be accessed through the API and that it does not represent opt-in to a store's email newsletters. The value is set for all customers by default and it refers to whether or not they will receive the "Abandoned Cart" or "Product Review" emails, if those are enabled in the store. If a customer opts out of those emails through the link in the email they receive, then this value will be changed to 'No'.